# Is there a continuous function $f:[0,\infty)\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ such that $\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{[0,t]}fd\mu$ exists but...?

Tags: lebesgue-integral

When I need to prove that $\int_{[0,\infty)}fd\mu<+\infty$ I usually think that if $\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{[0,t]}fd\mu<\infty$ then $\int_{[0,\infty)}fd\mu$ must converge, but someone told me that argument was not correct (Cosider $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure).

That is why I am looking for an example of a continuous function $f:[0,\infty)\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ such that $\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{[0,t]}fd\mu$ exists but $\int_{[0,\infty)}fd\mu$ is not defined.

So far I have not come up with any.

Comment: You misunderstand what they mean. consider $f=1\, \forall \,x\in \mathbb{R}$. then $\int_{[0,t]} 1 \, d\mu = t< \infty \ \forall t>0$ but it does obviously not converge.

Comment: @NikolajPedersen Sorry my question was not well. Now is ok. Your examample don't verify $lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{[0,t]}fd\mu<\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\frac {\sin x} x$ if $x >0$ and $f(0)=1$. Then $\lim_{t \to \infty} \int_{[0,t]}f(x)dx=\frac  {\pi} 2$. But $\int_{[0,\infty)} f(x)dx$ does not exist in Lebesgue sense. It is a general fact in Measure Theory  that if $\int fd\mu$ is finite then $\in |f|d\mu <\infty$. In this example it is known that $\int |f(x)|dx=\infty$. Hence, it follows that neither $f^{+}$ nor $f^{-}$ is not integrable and $\int fd\mu$ is not defined.

Comment: For f to be continuous, shouldn't we take f (0) = 1?

Comment: Yes, that was  a typo.  @HarryStone

Answer (score 0):

A classical example is the *Dirichlet integral* $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\int\limits_0^t\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\, dx = \pi/2$ although the function is not Lebesgue integrable. If you allow limits of integrals over $[-t,t]$, a trivial example is $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}\int\limits_{-t}^t x dx =0$.

Comment: I did not notice that Kavi Rama Murthy has beaten me by some minutes. His answer should hus the accepted one.